# Scalar product determining elements?

Tags: linear-algebra

Does anyone know a nice way to prove that an element in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is determined by its value in the scalar product against all elements? In other words the real numbers $<v,w>$ given $v$ and all $w$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This holds in any inner product space $\left(V, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle\right)$. Suppose there are $v, v' \in V$ with $\langle v, w \rangle = \langle v',w  \rangle$ for all $w \in V$. Then in particular $\langle v, v-v' \rangle =  \langle v', v-v' \rangle$. Therefore $$0 = \langle v, v-v' \rangle -  \langle v', v-v' \rangle =  \langle v-v', v-v' \rangle.$$
Since inner products are positive-definite, this implies $v-v'=0$ so $v=v'$.